# Printing a multi-line String token from Textbox into file

Tags: string, matlab, matlab-guide

Working on a Matlab guide, I want to take input from user using a text-box then print this input in a file to use it in many things.

The problem that the input string into the text box contains multiple lines.
when I print it to a file it's printed as a one line string and ordered as the program prints it column by column.
I tried to display the string that I get from the text box string using get handles to the console and it was shown correctly.

Now I wonder how can I print that multi-line string into a file with the same format?

I used the code :

```
fid = fopen('GUIDATA.txt','wt');
fprintf(fid,'%s',get(handles.equations,'String'));
fclose(fid);
```

and here is the result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp1jX.jpg
on the right the text box input and on the left the resulted text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the way Matlab organise the indexing of its arrays. If I simplify your example, you type:

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
```

in your text box. When you retrieve this string with `get`, look at the type of the variable which is returned. It is not a simple `string`, but a 2D array of `char`. In the case of the example above it's a [3x4] array.

*Note that if each line is not the same length, Matlab will pad the shortest lines with whitespace character until all lines are the same length.*

When you use `fprintf`, Matlab will write all the values contained in the variable sequentially. But without specific instruction, it does that in column order (Matlab is column major indexing, it means it counts index from top to bottom, then left to right).

To circumvent that, you should transpose your string/matrix before sending it to `fprintf`. But before that, you have to add a `newline` character *(`char(10)`)* at the end of each line (column of your matrix once it's transposed), because Matlab did not return that from the string which was in the edit box.

So doing:

```
str = get(handles.equations,'String') ;
str2print = [str.' ; repmat(char(10),1,size(str,1))] ; %// transpose and add newline character at the end of each column
fprintf(fid,'%s',str2print );
```

is a quick way to get in your file (almost) the same string as you had in your edit box.

---

Edit, just in case your lines are not the same length, for example:

```
aaa
bbbbb
cc
```

the quick version above will add a lot of necessary whitespace characters. To get rid of that, there is another way which unfortunately requires a loop but the result is cleaner in the end:

```
cellLines = cellstr( get(handles.equations,'String') ) ; %// retrieve each line in a cell

fid = fopen('GUIDATA.txt','wt');
for iline=1:size(cellLines,1)
    fprintf(fid,'%s\n',cellLines{iline} ); %// write each line of the cell array
end
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: @MahmoudYusuf, check my edit, may be it is more useful for you.